# Breadcrumb links in React Router not working with history.goBack

Tags: react-router, material-ui

I have a BreadCrumb in my project and want it to navigate to previous pages without refreshing the page

I tried this

```
render() {

        const goBack = (value) => history.goBack(value)
.
.
.
return (
  <div>
    <Link color="inherit"  href="#" onClick={goBack(3)}>
      <Typography>
        <Trans>DASHBOARD</Trans>
      </Typography>
    </Link>
    <Link color="inherit" href="#" onClick={goBack(2)}>
      <Typography>
        <Trans>SHELF READING</Trans>
      </Typography>
    </Link>
    <Link href="#" onClick={goBack(1)} color="inherit">
      <Typography>
        <Trans>SCANNING</Trans>
      </Typography>
    </Link>
    <Typography>ITEM DETAILS</Typography>
 </div>
```

But this does not work. How can I navigate through breadcrumb and not reload page

Comment: first of all, goBack should be: const goBack = (value) => () => history.goBack(value). second, do you have api calls taking effect when the page is loaded, in the pages you go back to?

Comment: There are no api calls. The error went away. but history.goBack(3) and history.goBack(2) just takes you to the previous page

Comment: Ok fixed it. I just used const goBack = (value) => () => history.go(value)